# limit point of a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If I have a compact metric space $Y$, continuous real function $g$, and a unique point $\rho$ such that $g(\rho)$ = inf $g(y)$,  $ \forall y \in Y$.

Clearly g is uniformly continuous. How can I show that $\rho$ is a limit point of $Y$?

If I have a sequence {$y_{n}$} $\in Y$  and  I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(y_{n})$ = $g(\rho)$. If I can show that $\rho$ is a limit point of $Y$, then I can argue that for every set {$y_{n}$},  $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_{n}$ = $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example: let $Y=[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ with metric $d(a,b)=|a-b|.$ Then $Y$ is compact.

Define $g:Y \to \mathbb R$ by

$g(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $g(2)=-1.$

Then we have $ \rho=2$, but $\rho$ is not a limit point of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question  but the following seems to be  a counterexample: let $Y=\{0\}\cup [1,2]$ and $g$ be the identity map. Then the hypothesis is satisfied with $\rho =0$ which is not a limit point of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you. Clearly my approach is wrong here.